# ReastJS, Node, and IIS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis

I have been following a tutorial from Cory House on Pluralsight about React, Redux, webpack, babel, and a bunch of other support libraries. I am using Visual Studio Code on a windows OS. I have completed the tutorial, which includes a build process that outputs a bundled js file to a dist folder. The build process also runs the app to verify the build is correct (which it is). I then tried to copy the contents up to an IIS server and run it there. However, when I try to access the web site, the index page comes up blank. I verified the bundled js file is called (returns 200 status). That left me wondering if there is an extra step I need to do to transfer an app created using Node to one that can run on IIS.

I should clarify I added a web.config file to the site.

Any help is appreciated

Edit: Here are two errors I am getting on when rendering the page. One of the errors (#2) appears to be a web pack module:

**Error 1**
[image: error 1]

**Error 2**
[image: error 2]

In error 2, "Attributes" is undefined

Comment: Your JavaScript file is loaded correctly? That means that the page itself must also have been loaded and it is likely not a problem caused by the platform. Do you see any errors/warnings in the browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out partially. It had to do with react-router and my routing. When developing and running it locally, it was running at the root of local host:

http://localhost

When I moved it to the IIS server, I had to create an app under the default web site, which changed the apps url to:

http://localhost/ReactJS

That caused my routing to fail and loaded a blank page. However, even though the home page loads now since fixing the routing, it is still not working as I can't navigate to the other views, but at least I have narrowed it down.